# GraalVM + Nashorn Cannot extend classes

Tags: nashorn, graalvm

I'm attempting to use graal + nashorn interop to write nodejs that interacts with Java.  I'm starting graal with `node --jvm --jvm.Xss2m --jvm.Dtruffle.js.NashornJavaInterop=true --jvm.classpath=libs/ --polyglot app.js`.  I cannot extend a class though.  The javascript code is

```
const GraaljsgrpcServiceImpl = Java.type('com.thing.GraaljsgrpcServiceImpl');
const HelloReply = Java.type('com.thing.HelloReply');
var GrpcImpl = Java.extend(GraaljsgrpcServiceImpl, {
    sayHello: function(request, responseObserver) {
        responseObserver.onNext(HelloReply.newBuilder().setMessage("Hello " + request.getName()).build());
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }
});
```

and my error is
`TypeError: Could not determine a class loader with access to the JS engine and class com.thing.GraaljsgrpcServiceImpl` This seems to point to a classloader issue with the java code I'm referencing and where the javascript is running(i.e. 2 different classloaders).  Is there a way to pull this off when using graal/nodejs?

Comment: It looks like if I add all my classes to the bootpath classloader I can extend things, but I'm also using guice, and that seems to interfere(plus, it's probably not great to have everything on the bootpath classloader)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for reporting this classloader problem. We are looking into that and should be able to fix that with our next release (0.32 expected early March).

Regarding the `--jvm.Dtruffle.js.NashornJavaInterop=true` flag: we strongly encourage not using that, but depending on the built-in interoperability of GraalVM. However, in this mode Graal.js is not 100% compatible with Nashorn/Rhino; for instance, we are not supporting `Java.extend` in that mode. Is `Java.extend` the only reason why you set the `NashornJavaInterop` flag?

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: I was using the interop flag for Java.extend and Java.type.  The Interop.import didn’t look usable in pure NodeJS since java hadn’t set a symbol on the Context, but I could be wrong there?

Comment: Optimally, you should just need `js --jvm --polyglot`. `Java.extend` is not  available then, but `Java.type` is.

`Interop.import` requires that the other language uses `Interop.export`. That's not the solution for Java code, it will work for JS<=>Ruby<=>R interop.